# Searching wikipedia through R

Tags: r, text-mining, wikipedia

I have a list of names in my dataframe and I want to find a way to query them in Wikipedia, although it's not as simple as just appending the name to "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/", I want to actually query Wikipedia so that there will be a suggestion even if its not spelt correctly. So for example if I were to put in Dick Dawkins, it'd come up with Richard Dawkins. I checked and that is actually the first hit on Wikipedia.

Ideally I'd want to use RVest but I don't want to manually get every url. Is this possible?

Comment: search_wiki <- function(x){
url(paste("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=", paste(x, collapse = "+"), "&go=Go&ns0=1", sep = ""))
};

search_wiki(c("Dick", "Dawkins"))

Comment: Thanks, so the actual items searched are inside the function? So I'd have to edit the function to search a different name?

Comment: No, you search for what you want by then doing, for example, `search_wiki(c("Rahim", "Dina"))`

Comment: Thanks, sorry but if this gives me the search results page, how I do I get it to pick the actual first hit. Like with the Dick Dawkins example, the first hit is Richard Dawkins but I want to actually search that page

Answer (score 2):

You are right. I, too, had a hard time getting Dick Dawkins out of the wikipedia. So much so that even searching for Dick Dawkins on the wikipedia search brought me straight to Richard Dawkins.

However, if you want to search for a term (say "Richard Dawkins") then Wikipedia has a proper API for you (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Tutorial).  You can play around and find the right parameters that work for you.

Just to get you started, I wrote a function (which is somewhat similar to rg255's post). You can change the parameter for MySearch function. Please make sure that spaces in search string are replaced by '%20' for every query from your dataframe.  Simple gsub function should do the job. You will also have to install 'jsonlite' package for this to work.

```r
library(jsonlite)
MySearch <- function(srsearch){
  FullSearchString <- paste("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=",srsearch,"&format=json",sep="")
  Response <- fromJSON(FullSearchString)
  return(Response)
}
Response <- MySearch("Richard%20Dawkins")
```

You can now use the parsed JSON to use the properties that you want. As I said, you will have to play with the parameters to get it right.

Please let me know if this is not what you wanted.